# Cannot run my Node.Js app with my machine's IP address, but can with localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have a node js app set up to listen on port 5050 of my machine:

So when I go to http://localhost:5050/myapp my app loads fine. I am using an express framwork, therefore my listen frame work is as follows:

```
var server = app.listen(5050, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log("App started on port 5050")
});
```

I also did a netstat(Am using windows 10 machine) and there are postivly no loopbacks to the local ip address.

However when I execute my machines ip eg. http://192.168.0.231:5050/myapp
I keep getting: This site can’t be reached

EDIT: I dont think I was being very clear

I have firewall turned off, I have tried without having an IP address specifiedin app.listen. I do not think it is an issue of the code, as when I try with just some simple test app and try run with my IP address, this also times out

Comment: Are you sure it's not `168` instead of `186`

Comment: Maybe your local subnet won't route to you; it depends on your network configuration.

Comment: Sorry- this was a typo

Comment: Check to make sure the ip is correct as in Pointy's answer, and also, Express doesn't require you to define an address. You could just pass the port and callback into the listen function.

Comment: Have you tried reaching that address from another machine on the same local network?

Comment: Yes I have tried from another machine and the same issues is happening, The ip address i am using is also correct.

Comment: Have you checked the browser log for any messages?

Comment: when running a nodejs application , i am also facing the same problem. Have u found any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try use listen without ip parameter

```
var server = app.listen(5050, function () {
   console.log("App started on port 5050")
});
```

Comment: I have tried without specifying the IP address and the same issue occurs

Comment: have you try to change port? (80-8080-...)

Comment: Firewall is on?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with the code, I can run the code fine when I specify localhost. Also, say I were to run another say test app for node js, it works fine also with local how- but as soon as I specefy and actual ip it times out.

Answer (score 0):

While running a nodejs application, i also faced the same issue as you mentioned. Before my code looks like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongoChat = require('./app/mongo_chat');

var ip = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 3000;
var users = {};
var WhisperChek = false;
var storage=[];
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
//socket connection
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        //console.log('Someone connected!');
        mongoChat.mognolizer(io,socket, users, WhisperChek);
        function updateNicknames() {
            io.emit('nickname', Object.keys(users));
        }
//disconnect socket
        socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
            if (!socket.Username)return;
            delete users[socket.Username];
            updateNicknames();
        });
    });
http.listen(port,ip, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But, I removed the `var ip="127.0.0.1"` from the code and updated the listen function as:

```
http.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

Now, my application is running both on localhost i.e., on `localhost:3000` and its also running on my ipaddress i.e., on `ipaddress:3000`. The problem there is when we give ip as `127.0.0.1` it only runs on the localhost, as ipaddress we use is private and it changes with the change in network connection. Check it once whether it works for you or not.